# Haskell case statements with ord 'x'

Tags: string, haskell, sum, case

```
import Data.Char  
x1 xs = sum(map (hilfsfunction) xs)
hilfsfunction x  
   | (ord 'x' > 97 && ord 'x' < 107) = (ord 'x' - 96)  
   | (ord 'x' > 48 && ord 'x' < 58) = (ord 'x' - 48)  
   | otherwise = 0
```

I need to write a programm where the function takes a string and then makes the following things with it:
- If the letter is an a, change it to 1
- If the letter is something else, I should take the equivalent number for it.
- All other symbols should be changed to 0

My problem now is, everytime I launch this programm the sum is 0, no matter if the first case or secound case is true.

Example: Lets take "6":

```
*Main Data.Char> ord '6' > 48 && ord '6' < 58
True
```

after this:

```
*Main Data.Char> ord '6' - 48
6
```

but if I take my function, everytime thats the case....:

```
*Main Data.Char> x1 "6"
[0]
```

I dont know where my error is.

Comment: You hardcoded the `'x'` character instead of using the `x` variable I guess.

Comment: Tuning on warnings would have spotted the error. I recommend to do that, and address each warning, especially those reporting missing type signatures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You here have **hardcoded the `'x'` character** instead of **using the `x` variable**:

```
import Data.Char  
x1 xs = sum(map (hilfsfunction) xs)
hilfsfunction x  
   | (ord 'x' > 97 && ord 'x' < 107) = (ord 'x' - 96)  
   | (ord 'x' > 48 && ord 'x' < 58) = (ord 'x' - 48)  
   | otherwise = 0
```

So that means Haskell does not care what the value of `x` is: it will simply use the `'x'`.

Note that here you write a rather cryptic function, you can write it in a cleaner way by making comparisons with other characters, and use `ord` when you do arithmetic:

```
hilfsfunction :: Char -> Int
hilfsfunction x  
   | 'a' <= x && x <= 'z' = ox - ord 'a' + 1
   | '0' <= x && x <= '9' = ox - ord '0'
   | otherwise = 0
    where ox = ord x
```

Here it is clear at first sight (without any knowledge of the outline of ASCII) that you first check if `x` is in the range `['a'..'z']`, and if that is the case you basically use its sequence number. If not that you check if it is in the range `['0' .. '9']` and then use its numerical counterpart, and otherwise you return `0`. In fact you made a mistake in your implementation, since `ord 'z'` is `122`, and not `107`. Although you *can* use `122`, by comparing against `'z'`, it is probably less likely to make mistakes, since you let Haskell translate characters to its ASCII code equivalent.

With the new definition for the `hilsfsfunction`, we obtain:

```
Prelude Data.Char> x1 "6aa@a1a~dwfwf123"
79
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it and edited my code :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a loss of information in the sum. First `'0'` is not included. Second, the range of `['1'..'9']` and `['a'..'i']` is the very same in the sum.

Also, if I were going to write this, I would

```
import Data.Char (ord)
sol x | elem x ['0'..'9'] = mod (ord x) 16
      | elem x ['a'..'z'] = mod (ord x) 32
      | elem x ['A'..'Z'] = mod (ord x) 64
      | otherwise = 0
```

With this, the preceding facts can be demonstrated

```
sol 'd' produces 4
sol '4' produces 4
sol '@' produces 0
sol '0' produces 0
```

Now that said, `ord` is an index into the ASCII character set.
It is possible to create you own index with just the characters that interest you.

```
tlz = zip [1..] $ concat [['0'..'9'],['a'..'z']]
```

Then you can lookup characters and each will have a unique index number, even zero '0' will register as one. If a character is not in the table it, simply is not counted. The list compression just emits a null `[]`.

Create the following function to use the list. The output is larger than the original function, the length of `tls` is 36 and originally the length is 26.

```
smmat = sum.concat.map (\x->[a|(a,b)<-tlz,x == b])
```

Just feed it a list.

```
smmat "This is 42% sure"
```

226

Be assured in the preceding list there were 11 "hits". take `sum` out of the list to see or changer `a` in the list comprehension to b to see the characters.